# How to insert same id after insert update in c#

Tags: mysql-workbench, c#

I'm trying to create an attendance project. I'm using `update` & `insert` in my code. Please check my code below. I know I'm vulnerable to SQL injection.

My problem is when I tried to Time In using the same ID even if I use that same ID for time out, it displays the time out not time-in. Any idea how I can time in again using same ID?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_student_list INNER JOIN attendance_tbl On  tbl_student_list.ID = attendance_tbl.stud_id   WHERE stud_id ='" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + "'", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("stud_id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value);
conn.Open();
MySqlDataReader DataRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataRead.Read();
```

This is my Update Code:

```
 //If already Time-In execute Time-Out


 if (DataRead.HasRows)
  {
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value = DataRead[1].ToString();
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value = DataRead[2].ToString();
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy/MM/dd");
  byte[] images = ((byte[])DataRead[3]);

   if (images == null)
   {
      pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
    else
    {
    MemoryStream mstreem = new MemoryStream(images);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstreem);
    conn.Close();
   conn.Open();
   string sqla = "Update attendance_tbl SET TimeOut = '" + Time + "' , Name ='" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + "'  where stud_id = '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + "'";
   cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqla, conn);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
```

This is My Insert Code:

```
//IF Not In Execute Time-In/Not exist in tbl attendance


 string sqlQu = "select ID,Name,Course,Image from tbl_student_list  where ID= '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + "'";
 md = new MySqlCommand(sqlQu, conn);
 MySqlDataReader DataReaders = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 DataReaders.Read();
 if (DataReaders.HasRows)
 {
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value = DataReaders[1].ToString();
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value = DataReaders[2].ToString();
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy/MM/dd");
  byte[] images = ((byte[])DataReaders[3]);
  if (images == null)
  {
     pictureBox1.Image = null;
  }
  else
  {
  MemoryStream mstreem = new MemoryStream(images);
  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstreem);
  Purpose f2 = new Purpose();
 if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value = f2.Rad;
  }
  conn.Close();
  conn.Open();
  string sql = "insert into attendance_tbl(stud_id,Date,Name,Course,Purpose,TimeIn)values('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + "','" + Date + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value + "','" + Time + "')";
     cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
```

Comment: This sounds like it's more a C# issue than a DBA issue.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Good luck finding what's wrong with it.  Eg. variable Time is never set.  When you execute dml, you don't care if it succeeded or not.  Modify the DML to use bind variables.  Then update your question.